# File not found while using \input for gnuplot figures

Tags: graphics, pdftex, input, include, gnuplot

I have a figure `fig_name.eps` with the surrounding text in `fig_name.tex`.

They are in a sub directory called fig_dir. I used the following in the beginning of my document to change the path for `input`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{/path/to/fig_dir/}}
\makeatother
```

I am using `\input{fig_name}` to include the figure. On compilation it shows error that file not found. What did I do wrong?

Edit : I am adding a MWE below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}

%TO INCLUDE FIGURES FROM FOLDER NAMED fig_dir
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{/path/to/fig_dir/}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%THIS ONE WORKS FINE
   \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=7cm]{fig_dir/bla_bla.png}
      \caption{bla_bla}
   \end{figure}

%THIS ONE DOESN'T
   \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \resizebox{!}{0.30\textwidth}{\input{fig_name}}
       \caption{fig_name}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I put `fig_name.eps` and `fig_name.tex` in the current directory and remove the comments for changing the path of input, it works fine. But I need to put figures from sub directory.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your problem (i.e. with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`)?

Comment: Thank you! I added a MWE. Let me know if that's enough information or you need anything else.

Comment: A lot of code (packages loading) is not needed here (-;. Anyway, `\input{<file-name>}` means: "*copy-past the content of `file-name.tex` right here*". So if your file is `fig_name.png` you need to use `\includegraphics` and not `\input`. In this case, the command you want is `\graphicspath{{/path/to/folder1/}{/path/to/folder2/}}` and not `\def\input@path{}`.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten the beginning of your question. What is in your file `fig_name.tex`?

Comment: LaTeX will use `\input@path` *only* if the typesetting engine uses different search paths for `\openin` and for `\@@input` (= the `\input` TeX primitive).  Since this is *not* the case for almost all of today’s implementations, your setting of `\input@path` is almost surely disegarded by LaTeX.  And it is good it is, because it would break down *lots* of crucial things!

Comment: While plotting (using gnuplot) I set my terminal to epslatex and I get  two files : .tex and .eps. While the latter contains only the plotted figure, the former has all the information about the axis ticks, title, font size etc. As I said, it works fine when figures are in the current  directory, which means I am missing something on how to tell `\input` that my figures are in a sub directory.

Comment: On second thought, [my previous comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324162/file-not-found-while-using-input-for-figures#comment791755_324162) is not correct: LaTeX will nonetheless use `\input@path` if it cannot find the requested file via `\openin`.

Answer (score 5):

gnuplot's `epslatex` terminal creates two files `fig_name.tex` and `fig_name.eps`.
You have to call `fig_name.tex` from your main file with `\input{fig_name}`, but this one will load `fig_name.eps` with an `\includegraphics` command. Open `fig_name.tex` with an editor and will find a line with contents:

```
\put(0,0){\includegraphics{fig_name}}%
```

So the easyest solution would be to add a `\graphicspath` command with the `subfiles` folder and call the `.tex` file with `\input{subfile/fig_name}`.

Now suppose gnuplot created `mytest.tex` and `mytest.eps`, and both are stored in subfolder `gnuplot`. Following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{gnuplot/}}

\begin{document}

\input{gnuplot/mytest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I believed after adding graphics path I don't need to mention the entire path inside `input` which is not correct. This worked!

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.  The following works fine for me:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{graphics}

\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{Sub_dir/}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

Some random text.
\begin{figure}[tbp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{Where are you? \input{HereAmI}}
    \caption{My figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Save the above code in a certain directory, then create, inside that same directory, a subdirectory named `Sub_dir`; save the following code in a file named `HereAmI.tex` placed inside `Sub_dir`:

```
Here am~I\@!
```

Does this work correctly?